# Is that possible to save data user from Auth0 Social(e.g facebook) to Database(mysql) after login via facebook(auth0 social)? (using ionic framework)

Tags: ionic-framework, auth0

I've used Auth0 service into my Ionic project to create a login page and it's working with my own-database connection.
All I want to do is to save the data from social(e.g facebook) to my own-database. Is that possible?
I've tried using social login in auth0, but those profile data is saved on my Auth0 account. I need those data to be saved in my own-database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that in a rule. [Taken from a post at ask.auth0.com](https://ask.auth0.com/t/add-social-account-users-to-the-custom-databae/969/2?u=rodrigo):

```js
function (user, context, callback) {
  if (context.connectionStrategy === 'connection') {
    // store user data in database
  }
  callback(null, context, callback);
}
```